# ComponentOne wijmo data-binding

Tags: data-binding, componentone, wijmo

I wasn't able to find the answer to this question in the C1 documentation. Is it possible to bind the ComponentOne wijmo grid to the DefaultView of a System.Data.DataTable?  The examples I've seen show the grid being told where to find a MS-Access MDB file and the grid's datasource is being set to a sql select statement. But I'd like to know if it's possible to do something like this, in *server-side* (e.g. C#) code:

```
              // myFunc has a command that executes a SP on the server
              // and it returns a DataTable
              System.Data.DataTable T = myFunc(... );
              myWijmoGrid.DataSource = T.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The Wijmo GridView implements CompositeDataBoundControl so it can be bound to any DataSource in ASP.NET. For instance it can be bound to DataTables, SqlDataSource, LinqDataSource, etc.